# How can you get a -5 reputation change?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Recently I saw a -5 rep change in my history related to a question for which I posted an answer. This seems a bit odd. A downvote causes -2 change as far as I know and if your answer was marked as the answer and then got changed this is not shown in the history at all (but would be a nice feature btw.). Now my answer to the question was not downvoted and it was never the accepted answer as far as I know so how could I have gotten a -5 change?

Comment: While obviously Mark has shown how this happened for you, to me the most likely possibility would be someone removing an upvote on a question.

Comment: @glowcoder: Yeah, but I remember posts on meta saying "I lost 15 rep because someone removed an accepted answer but I don't know where". Somehow I was under the impression that was still the case but apparently that feature got added.

Comment: @glowcoder But removed upvotes won't show as rep loss.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: Apparently they do, see Marks answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220986/chriswue?tab=reputation) shows you how:

[image: Reputation audit]

You received an up-vote on an answer (+10) and someone unaccepted a different, previously accepted answer of yours (-15), resulting in a -5 net reputation change.

Comment: *smack* Not sure how I missed that - I feel a bit embarrassed now ;)